# How to make a responsive right aligned login box to center, when viewed in different screen sizes using media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive, center-align

I made a responsive login form with a login box aligned to the right, but I want my login box to display in the center at different screen sizes using CSS media queries.

My current CSS code is:

```
enter code here 
.login {  
position: absolute;  
top: 8em;   
right: 5vw;  
}  
.login-card {  
    min-width: 20vw;  
    max-width: 25em;  
    min-height: 20vh;  
    max-height: 25em;}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? I see you are new to the site so i suggest you take the [StackOverflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to understand how everything works, but SO is not a place to ask for peoples to do your job, in order to help you out we will need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little bit general, but the question doesn't give me much information about your issue. It's recommended to give at least a snippet of the code you're struggling with

With that out of the way, I would insert some CSS attributes on the media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    your_login_panel {
        display: block;
        width: 300px; /* the wished size for your login panel */
        margin: 20px auto; /* the second attribute has to be auto, this value combined with display:block will center the element inside the element that it's located */
    }
}
```

If you are using `position: absolute` to align your element to the right, remember to insert `position: inherit` inside the media query to overwrite this value.

**UPDATE**
Now with the snippet, I can see that your CSS is not stating a left attribute, this is pretty useful to align something to the right. In order to center it, just add a `left:` property to your media query with the same value of the right attribute, the CSS will try to satisfy both attributes, you should also put an `margin: auto;` attribute, to give the CSS more freedom to play around with the margin and center the login panel.
Your media query should look somehow like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .login {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 8em;   
    right: 0px;   
    left: 0px;
    margin: auto;
  }  
  .login-card {  
     min-width: 20vw;  
     max-width: 25em;  
     min-height: 20vh;  
     max-height: 25em;
  }   
}
```

Comment: thanks man for the answer, i shared my code snippet. can u suggest me smethng ?

Comment: @Rambo Sure! I have just updated my answer, please check it out to see if it works now :) Also I explained a little so you can get an idea why I did what I did.

Comment: It worked lyk a charm, May the force be with you always :)

Comment: @Rambo, whohooo! Great! Thanks for the feedback! Now please remember to tag your question as SOLVED, and to check this answer as the solution for it. So other visiting users can also know what worked for you ;)

Comment: Hey, this doesnt work in landscape, tho i have added another query with orientaion to landscape, the login card dimensions remain fixed n i cant change them.

Comment: When you are on landscape, the width of your screen is bigger than 768px. Therefore this CSS media query won't take place.
Feel free to change and create more media queries with different values to support multiple screen widths. Also check some documentation about it on the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the display of the parent element of the login box as `flex`, you can set the normal display position of the login box on the right hand side, using:

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

and write a @media query in which the value changes to:

```
justify-content: center;
```

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 255);
}

section {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
padding: 24px 12px;
background-color: rgb(163, 163, 255);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

form.login {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
grid-template-columns: 88px auto;
grid-row-gap: 6px;
width: 240px;
padding: 12px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(95, 95, 255);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

section {
justify-content: center;
}

}
```

```html
<section>
<form class="login">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="username" placeholder="Username" />


<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password"/>
</form>
</section>

<p>On a narrower screen, the login box appears in the center.<br />
Try switching to <strong>Full page</strong>, to see the login box move over to the right hand side.
```

Comment: tnq for ur answer, i gave my css code. can u suggest me smethng?

Comment: Yes. Give the `.login` a parent with `display: flex` - then you can switch between `justify-content: flex-end` and `justify-content: center` in your @media queries.

Answer (score 0):

use media screen for making responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){   
 .login {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 8em;
    left: 0;   
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;  
    }  
    .login-card {  
        min-width: 20vw;  
        max-width: 25em;  
        min-height: 20vh;  
        max-height: 25em;
    } 
}
```